# Given 30 people,in how many possible ways there are 6 months having birthday of 2 people each and 6 months having birthday of 3 people each.

Tags: combinatorics

Given 30 people,in how many possible ways there are 6 months having birthday of 2 people each and 6 months having birthday of 3 people each.

My attempt:

There are ${12 \choose 6}$ ways of selecting the 6 months having 2 birthdays each, and we automatically select the other six months having 3 birthdays each.

Now, we can classify the months as 12 boxes, and the people as balls. So, we can arrange and permute the people in $30!$ ways.

I don't think we need to find the arrangements of the month and I don't think that I have the correct answer yet, I think I am overcounting and I don't know where. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After your ${12 \choose 6}$ ways of choosing the six "pair months" and six "triple months", you then have ${30 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing the two individuals in the first "pair month", ${28 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing the two individuals in the second "pair month", . . . , ${18 \choose 3}$ ways of choosing the two individuals in the first "triple month", ${15 \choose 3}$ ways of choosing the two individuals in the second "triple month", . . . .

Multiply all these together and you get $\displaystyle{12 \choose 6}\dfrac{30!}{(2!)^6 (3!)^6}$.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what struck me after I posted the question. Thank you for verifying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, it just happened to me, I just thought maybe it is correct.

There are ${12 \choose 6}$ ways to choose the 6 months having 2 birthdays each, and automatically we are choosing the other 6 months.

Now, the 3 birthdays in a month 6 times and 2 birthdays in a month 6 times can be chosen in

$${30 \choose 3~3~3~3~3~3~2~2~2~2~2~2}$$ ways, and hence the answer. Is it correct? Please confirm. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is conventional to put commas in [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients), but apart from that it looks as if your answer is the same as mine